# jqBootstrapValidation on input type number

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As far as I understand, jqBootstrapValidation should automatically validate html5 elements, like this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="ordPrice" placeholder="Price" data-validation-number-message="Not a number">
```

But, it doesn't. Here is my js bind:

```
$('#create_form').find('input,select,textarea').not('[†ype="submit"], [type="file"]').jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,        
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        console.log('error!');
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        console.log('success!');
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(':visible');
    }
});
```

Am I missing something very elementary here?

Answer (score 2):

Although the docs do not make clear the plugin only works on formatted  for / with bootstrap forms.

To get you example work your input should look like at least:

```
<div class="control-group"> 
  <div class="controls"> 
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ordPrice" placeholder="Price" data-validation-number-message="Not a number">
  </div>
</div>
```

Without the `control-group` and `controls` it won't work. The structure of from inputs has changed with Twitter's Bootstrap 3. The `control-group` has been replace with `form-group` and many other changes. For this reason this plugin in not ready to use with Twitter's Bootstrap 3.

Also see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-states (Validation states). You should try to let your validators use this maybe.